# Is there a way to refresh a tkinter frame in which widgets have been reconfigured?

Tags: python, tkinter, refresh, configure

I'd like to allow the user to configure the appearance of the app (background color, font, font size and color, button color, etc). I've got all of the default settings saved into a config file, which the program interprets and saves into variables within a class for easy access between functions. Now, I can save the changes the user made into the config file and those changes will be reflected when the user closes and reopens the app, but I'd like the changes to be instantaneous, so I tried something like this:

```
import tkinter as tk

class SetColor:
    def __init__(self, color):
        self.color = 'green'
current = SetColor('green')

root = tk.Tk()

lbl_color = tk.Label(root, text='Choose button color')
lbl_color.grid(row=0, column=0, pady=5, padx=2)

btn_red = tk.Button(root, text='Red', bg=current.color, command=lambda:update_color('red'))
btn_red.grid(row=0, column=1, pady=5, padx=2)

btn_green = tk.Button(root, text='Green', bg=current.color, command=lambda:update_color('green'))
btn_green.grid(row=0, column=2, pady=5, padx=2)

btn_blue = tk.Button(root, text='Blue', bg=current.color, command=lambda:update_color('blue'))
btn_blue.grid(row=0, column=3, pady=5, padx=2)

def update_color(color):
    current.color = color
    #THIS is where I'm wondering if there's a way to refresh without individually updating each widget as I've done below
    btn_red.config(bg=current.color)
    btn_green.config(bg=current.color)
    btn_blue.config(bg=current.color)       
    
root.mainloop()
```

This does work, but in my actual app there are a loooooot more widgets that would need updating than in this^ example. So I have a feeling I'm missing something or going about this in the wrong way. Any help greatly appreciated :)

Comment: Bit confused, if above code is working. What exactly are you looking for?

Comment: @Meritor I'm looking for a way to do essentially what I've done above without having to hardcode the configuration changes for every single widget in the entire program. The above works fine for these three little buttons, but I've got probably hundreds of widgets that need to be updated. Will try the answer from Maarten T. and see how that goes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your best bet is to store the buttons in a list and loop over that list. This way you can seperate different buttons. But if you are sure you want to change the color of every singlle button you can do: `for widget in root.winfo_children():`
`if isinstance(widget, tk.Button):`
`widget.config(bg=current.color)`

Comment: This worked perfectly, thanks! Also, I found that if you're looking to exclude a particular widget, `cget(key)` works pretty well. Example: If the 'EXIT' button should never change color, can include a line in for loop `if widget.cget('text') == 'EXIT': pass`. Thanks again :D

Answer (score 0):

@Maarten's answer is perfect for the tkinter button.
There is another option using ttk.Button can be used in such scenario

###### create the button object with a custom style

```
btn_green = ttk.Button(root, text='Green', style="color.TButton", command=lambda: update_color('green'))
```

###### create style object

```
style = ttk.Style()
style.theme_use("default")
```

###### set the style

```
style.configure('color.TButton', background=current.color)
# Activate is when you mouse over the button.
style.map('color.TButton', background=[('active', current.color)])
```

###### Full example:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk


class SetColor:
    def __init__(self, color):
        self.color = 'green'


def update_color(color):
    current.color = color
    # Let's set the style
    # naming that style variable as color.TButton
    # NOTE: .TButton is important, you can add any other pretix though
    style.configure('color.TButton', background=current.color)

    # Activate is when you mouse over the button.
    style.map('color.TButton', background=[('active', current.color)])


current = SetColor('green')

root = tk.Tk()


# Create style Object
style = ttk.Style()
# Setting theme to default (built in themes can be found https://wiki.tcl-lang.org/page/List+of+ttk+Themes)
style.theme_use("default")

lbl_color = ttk.Label(root, text='Choose button color')
lbl_color.grid(row=0, column=0, pady=5, padx=2)

btn_red = ttk.Button(root, text='Red', style="color.TButton", command=lambda: update_color('red'))
btn_red.grid(row=0, column=1, pady=5, padx=2)

btn_green = ttk.Button(root, text='Green', style="color.TButton", command=lambda: update_color('green'))
btn_green.grid(row=0, column=2, pady=5, padx=2)

btn_blue = ttk.Button(root, text='Blue', style="color.TButton", command=lambda: update_color('blue'))
btn_blue.grid(row=0, column=3, pady=5, padx=2)

update_color(current.color)

root.mainloop()
```

There are a lot more options with ttk style to play around.

Have a look at

[Python ttk Style](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tkinter.ttk.html#tkinter.ttk.Style)

[ttk Themes](https://wiki.tcl-lang.org/page/List+of+ttk+Themes)

Comment: Thank you! I'd figured there was prob a way to do it with ttk, but I was curious if there was a way with just tkinter, so I wouldn't have to go back and change all the widgets I'd already made. Thanks for the info :D

Comment: ahh alright. No worries.. this answer may be useful for someone else. :)

Answer (score 0):

I did this and works perfectly. I hope it works for you.

```
def groups1(): #  This function is to place the widgets for Groups.
    #  Clean widgets immediately after you call the button inside 
    # the button function.
    for widget in frameleft.winfo_children():
        widget.destroy()
    groups = tkinter.ttk.Label(frameleft, text='Grupos', font= 
            ('URW Gothic', 20))
    groups.place(x=20, y=30)
```